# how to put state into value in Autocomplete in MaterialUi React

Tags: reactjs, redux, autocomplete, material-ui

I have Autocomplete and a reset button. I need that pressing the button my state was reset. So I need to use state as a value in Autocomplete. Can I do it? (state.type="") I use class components

```
<Autocomplete
            className={classes.root}
            id="combo-box-demo"
            options={availableTypes}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
            onChange={this.changeType}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                className={classes.wrapper}
                {...params}
                label="choose any type"
              />
            )}
          />
```

Comment: do you want o clear the selected value of autocomplete on a button click?

Comment: Can you share the code on code sandbox

Comment: yes, I want to clear selected value

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete does provide a clear button with the textfield itself but if you still want control this behaviour using another button, you can do something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-autocomplete-input-ut0bs).

Comment: thank you for advise, but I do not have a button. I reset state and want Autocomplete was clead also.

Comment: check the same example. I am maintaining the state for type as well.